# Automatic factory generators for constructor DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, factory, factory-pattern, reflection.emit

I would like to use factory-based dependency injection without passing any "kernel"-container so that it's impossible to instantiate a class without having its dependencies explicitely passed from the "top".

The manual way to do so requires code like this in a bootstrap:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // simplified example, can require classes in reality
        ABFactory abFactory = (data1) => new AB(data1);
        ACAFactory acaFactory = (data1) => new ACA(data1);
        ACFactory acFactory = (x) => new AC(x, acaFactory);
        IA a = new A(1, new AA(1, new AAA(), new AAB()), abFactory, acFactory);
        a.Action(123);
    }
```

When factories are defined as

```
delegate IAB ABFactory(string data1);
delegate IAC ACFactory(int x);
delegate IACA ACAFactory(int data1);
```

Is there anything I can use to make factory building easier or even automatic? With different factory types support (pool, ThreadLocal cache, etc)?

***UPDATE***

Some real code example:

```
public interface IItemSetSpawnController
{
    void TransitSpawned();
}

public class ItemSetSpawnController : IItemSetSpawnController
{
    readonly GameMap.ItemSet _set;
    readonly LootableFactoryDelegate _lootableFactory;
    readonly IFiber _fiber;

    readonly int _defaultRespawnTime;

    public ItemSetSpawnController([NotNull] GameMap.ItemSet set, int defaultRespawnTime, [NotNull] LootableFactoryDelegate lootableFactory, IFiber fiber)
    {
        if (set == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(set));
        if (lootableFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(lootableFactory));
        if (set.Items.Count == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Empty set", nameof(set));
        _set = set;
        _lootableFactory = lootableFactory;
        _fiber = fiber;
        _defaultRespawnTime = defaultRespawnTime;
    }

    public void TransitSpawned()
    {
        // Fiber.Schedule for respawning
    }
}

public delegate IItemSetSpawnController ItemSetSpawnControllerFactory(
    [NotNull] GameMap.ItemSet set, int defaultRespawnTime, [NotNull] LootableFactoryDelegate lootableFactory, IFiber fiber);


protected virtual void AddMapLootables()
{
    foreach (var set in ItemSets)
    {
        if (set.Items.Count == 0) continue;
        var c = ItemSetSpawnControllerFactory(
            set,
            Settings.LootRespawnTime,
            LootableFactory,
            ExecutionFiber);
        c.TransitSpawned();
    }

}
```

Comment: Autofac has this concept built-in: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your components are initialized with runtime data. This is [bad practice](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99), because this will complicate your DI configuration a lot, and I think that this is the case in your case.

Instead of using a factory to initialize a component where the component's constructor depends on both service dependencies and runtime data, move the runtime data out of the constructor and supply it to the component at runtime. You can either do this by passing the runtime value through the component's method, or you can inject a service into the component that allows the component to request that value at runtime (after initialization).

Which option to choose, depends on whether the use of the runtime value is an implementation detail. If it's an essential part of the abstraction, the value should be part of the abstraction's method signature. If it's of no concern to the abstraction, and only the component itself should know about it, injection of a service that allows access to this runtime value is the most obvious solution.

**UPDATE**

If you move runtime data out of the constructors you will be able to remove the need to use the factory as extra layer of abstraction and you can change the code to something like this:

```
public interface IItemSetSpawnController {
    void TransitSpawned(GameMap.ItemSet set);
}

public class ItemSetSpawnController : IItemSetSpawnController {
    readonly LootableFactoryDelegate _lootableFactory;
    readonly IFiber _fiber;
    readonly ISessings settings;
    public ItemSetSpawnController(ISessings settings,
        [NotNull] LootableFactoryDelegate lootableFactory, IFiber fiber) {
        _lootableFactory = lootableFactory;
        _fiber = fiber;
        _settings = settings;
    }
    public void TransitSpawned([NotNull] GameMap.ItemSet set) {
        if (set == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(set));
        // If LootRespawnTime is a config value that doesn't change after startup, you
        // can more it back into the constructor of the controller.
        int defaultRespawnTime = _settings.LootRespawnTime;
        // Fiber.Schedule for respawning
    }
}

class MapLooter {
    IItemSetSpawnController controller;
    public MapLooter(IItemSetSpawnController controller){
        this.controller = controller;
    }
    public void AddMapLootables() {
        foreach (var set in ItemSets) {
            if (set.Items.Count == 0) continue;
            this.controller.TransitSpawned(set);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a usual approach -  passsing a contextual data to constructors. Actually if a class gets instantiated without a context then it should be singleton. I understand that you suggest to move such context initialization code to a seperate method included to interface but it looks a little weird for me...

Comment: @Vlad: If you update your question and make your code more specific (with the actual names of the abstractions and components you are trying to create), I can give a concrete example of how to improve your design.

Comment: I'm sorry if it was not clear from my code but.. the purpose of ItemSetSpawnController is to contain respawn logic (with timers, subscription to pickup events) for one single set. Therefore it should be constructed for *each* ItemSet.

Comment: @Vlad: It should be recreated, or you like it to be recreated? In my experience, it's much better to keep your application components stateless. This leads to much easier code, and object graphs that are much easier to verify.

Comment: It's not a one-time object. As I said it maintains a respawn logic for single ItemSet through the Game lifetime (Game is also a runtime object instantiated for each game room on server). In my practice it's better to deal with attached to context classes than have one instance to manage a collection of objects. E.g. it allows to have non-standard respawn implementation for some ItemSets. Almost everything in my application are context-attached runtime objects (even Settings can be different per each Game instance) except a few singletons.

Comment: Also with context-attached logic my classes have more strict responsibility so ItemSetSpawnController class doesn't care if there is collection of ItemSets or only single ItemSet. Of course in your example it doesn't deal with a collection too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88700/discussion-between-vlad-and-steven).